# DbSet.Where in EF fetching all the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have using the below code to fetch the matching data based on the where parameter and then removing them but not sure why in the log the query which gets executed shows that it is first fetching all the records from table irrespective of the where filter.

```
void function(Func<TEntity, bool> where) 
{
    IQueryable objects = DbSet.Where<TEntity>(where).AsQueryable();
    foreach(var obj in objects) 
        DbSet.remove(obj) ;
}
```

Comment: When app starts using Entity the DbSet need to filled by a query to the database.  The project contains a connection string which will tell what database is being used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework uses expression trees to be able to convert lambda expression to sql. You are taking a `Func<TEntity, bool>`, this causes the DbSet to be converted to a IEnumerable.Where, rather than using a IQueryable.Where, causing all items to be fetched.

You should probably replace the parameter with an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`. Note that not all expressions can be converted to SQL, and this may result in runtime errors, so you need to be a bit careful how you write expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to look for this but not able to hit this point.... It works like a charm....